# Unity3D - Counter always back to ZERO

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zero

i create simple counter using Unity3D with C#. it's purpose to count total of click to a button.

if i test at unity3d editor, it's fine... **counter will count up.**

but every time i test to device, if i click counter button, then **it always back to zero**.

any idea ?

below are the source codes :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class z_manual : MonoBehaviour {

    private int counter;
    public GameObject textCounter;

    public void addCounter()
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
        textCounter.GetComponent<Text> ().text = counter.ToString ();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Note :
1) Button Click will call method `addCounter()`
2) textCounter is Normal Unity UI Text

Comment: Strange. Try to initialise `counter` to `0` and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Add `counter = 0;` to the Start() method

Comment: What platform are you targeting? What does your scene setup look like? Do you use il2cpp? What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: I believe on local  uninitialized variables in C# are undefined behavior, unless the compiler turns it into a nop, I doubt it's the reason for the bug.